# Matlab OpenMP mex uses only 1 thread when called for the second time

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, openmp, mex

I found a frustrating problem when running a multi-threading mex file (with OpenMP) I compiled. The source code of the mex file can be found here

https://github.com/fangq/mmc/blob/master/mmc/trunk/src/mmclab.cpp#L123

it was compiled and linked with the proper options using gcc/mex on a Ubuntu box. the matlab mex is from matlab 8.2.

When I ran it for the first time in matlab, it used 8 threads on an i7 processor, as expected. However, if I run it again in the same matlab session, it only uses 1 thread! In order to use 8 threads, I had to close matlab and start again.

I tried to add "setenv('OMP_NUM_THREADS','8');" in my script, it did not help. I checked the parallel preference, I did not see anything related.

has anyone encountered similar problem before?

what might be wrong?

Comment: one update, if I call "clear all", the mex can be executed again with all 8 threads. if I only call "clear mexfilename", it still run the mex with 1 thread. so it looks like matlab has an internal state that was mistakenly set when the mex run for the first time.

Comment: Does your code have any kind of state that makes it run differently the second time?

Comment: I dont have experience with openMP but doing stuff with Matlab and CUDA. When this happened to me was because I was not "shutting down" the CUDA stuff properly. This may happen with openMP also. Are you sure you end properly your paralel pool?